# Kivy - Bottom and right position widget and margim

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to put the widget in the bottom and right position, with  margin of 16dp, however I've tried it in a number of ways, with several layouts and it does not work. Can anybody help me?

**ex35.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

class Ex35(App):
    pass

Ex35().run()
```

**ex35.kv**

```
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'

    Widget:
        id: ellipse
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (dp(56), dp(56))
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pos_hint`? What exactly do you mean a margin of 16dp? Like a space of 16dp from the right and bottom?

Comment: Margim 16dp I got it by adding `pos: (dp(16), dp(16))` in Ellipse. What I'm not getting is to take Ellipse to the right in bottom

Answer (score 0):

I got it with the code below:

```
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'
        Button:
            text:'Hello'

    Widget:
        id: ellipse
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (dp(56), dp(56))
        pos_hint:{'right': 1}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: [dp(self.pos[0]) - dp(16), dp(self.pos[1]) + dp(16)]
```

[image]